# Collation with ORDER BY ordinal

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

When running a TSQL query in one particular scenario I don't know in advance a column name I need to sort by, but I know its ordinal position, so I can do something like

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

Recently a need arose to add collation to that sorting. And while collation would work with ORDER BY column name, something like

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY 1 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ASC
```

throws an error. Is there a way to achieve this - add collation to sorting while still keep sorting by ordinal?

Comment: AFAIK you must use a column name/alias/expression. (Order by ordinal position has been deprecated for decades.)

Comment: @jarlh That is the answer sir. :-)

Comment: You might have mentioned that the error is: `Expression type int is invalid for COLLATE clause.`